# Play/Pause YoutubePlayer programmatically after activity resume from background

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

My application has activity A for playing Youtube video (using YoutubePlayerFragment) This activity A has an own button B to control playback. When activity loaded and is playing a video, I can use B button to control playback. Then I press Home button. When I resume activity A from recent task menu, the button B does not work anymore. I can only play video from its own Play button (inside YoutubePlayerFragment).
Currently I store YoutubePlayer instance when `onInitializationSuccess` is called:

```
private val onInitializedListener = object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider, youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, wasRestored: Boolean) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "YoutubePlayer - onInitializationSuccess")
        if (!wasRestored) {
            mYoutubePlayer = youTubePlayer
            mYoutubePlayer!!.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener)
            mYoutubePlayer!!.setPlaybackEventListener(mPlaybackEventListener)
            mYoutubePlayer!!.setShowFullscreenButton(false)
            mYoutubePlayer!!.loadVideo(mCurrentVideoId)
        } else {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Restored from a previously saved state")
        }
    }

    override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider, youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError) {
            youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this@KActivityPlayVideo, 1).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this@KActivityPlayVideo,
                    "Failed to initialize video, please try again!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Button B uses this YoutubePlayer instance to call Play/Pause upon request. But when activity A goes to background and resume, this does not work anymore. Could anyone suggest me what is the problem here please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi ! I'am strugling with the same issue did you find out a solution ?

Comment: Just found a hack, added mYoutubePlayer.play() in onStop() and every started working fine. It is not proper but couldn't find any other solution.

Answer (score -1):

i hope this is will help you .

```
private final class MyPlaybackEventListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        // Called when playback starts, either due to user action or call to play().

    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        // Called when playback is paused, either due to user action or call to pause().

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        // Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused.

    }

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
        // Called when buffering starts or ends.
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int i) {
        // Called when a jump in playback position occurs, either
        // due to user scrubbing or call to seekRelativeMillis() or seekToMillis()
    }
}
```

Comment: I also register for PlaybackEventListener. After activity resume, 'onStopped' is invoked automatically. According to document, this is "Called when playback stops for a reason other than being paused, such as the video ending or a playback error." I just can't figure out what's wrong here. Btw, adding this wont solve anything as  I already registered this listener.